# How to destroy / dispose Bootstrap tooltip with specifc css class in dynamic HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I need to destroy tooltip function in dynamic HTML content in especific resolution. But not all only those than has class "withTooltipLg"

Example:

**HTML**

```
<a id="innerCollapse1" class="withTooltipLg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Volver a Datos de Auto/moto">
  <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'});

});
$(window).resize(function(){
  if(jQuery(window).width() < 768){
        //here i should do something like: (pseudo)
        $('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"].withTooltipLg'}).destroy()
     }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That mean you want to remove all element tooltip from document ?

Comment: Hi @Som. Thanks in advance! No,  I only want to dispose/destroy tooltips with class "withTooltipLg", because i don't like the behavior of them in mobile. But there are other links that i want to still showing tooltip

Comment: use `$('body .withTooltipLg').tooltip().destroy();` as given in answare

Comment: can't you just use the bootstrap  responsive utilities?

Comment: You want to say that hiding with bootstrap responsive class or hidding the tooltip with css using media querys? No, because tooltips are drawing in the bottom of the body tag and I can't select them

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with your jquery selector. If you want to destroy all tooltips in the body of your page with the class `withTooltipLg`, you just need to form your selector to grab those elements.

`$('body .withTooltipLg').tooltip().destroy();`

Final code ends up looking like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'});
   if(jQuery(window).width() < 768)
      $('body .withTooltipLg').tooltip().destroy();
});
```

Comment: No because is dynamic content, the elements with class "withTooltipLg" don't exist in the DOM when I call the dispose function

Comment: In that case, you just call `$('body .withTooltipLg').tooltip().destroy();` after you initialize your elements into the DOM.

Comment: Besides, if the tooltip elements are dynamic, the document.ready wouldn't work for initializing those elements. This would need to go into your ajax success or however you are initializing the dynamic elements.

Comment: Yes, I know that I put a bad example. I'm going to try in the ajax success function as you said. Thank you @rich